# installing webpack globally with npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am not familiar to node environment. I ran this on my `OSX` machine

```
sudo npm install -g webpack
```

it installed successfully there, and outputs on the console

```
/usr/local/bin/webpack -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
```

But when I ran the `grunt` command, which requires `require('webpack');` in the `grunt.js` file, then I get this message

```
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

Then I tried to follow some `SO` posts and ran `npm install`. But then running `grunt` gives me a bunch of errors related to `react`, `react-dom`, etc...

Btw, when I first launched the command `npm install`, I got these warnings

```
npm WARN react-dom@15.4.1 requires a peer of react@^15.4.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-select@1.0.0-beta5 requires a peer of react@^0.14.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-select@1.0.0-beta5 requires a peer of react-dom@^0.14.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-input-autosize@0.6.13 requires a peer of react@^0.14 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^15.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-webpack@1.0.18 requires a peer of webpack@1.x but none was installed.
npm WARN webpack-dev-server@1.16.2 requires a peer of webpack@>=1.3.0 <3 but none was installed.
npm WARN webpack-dev-middleware@1.8.4 requires a peer of webpack@1 || ^2.1.0-beta but none was installed.
npm WARN mapapp@1.8.0 No repository field.
npm WARN mapapp@1.8.0 No license field.
```

UPDATE :

here's the content of the `webpack.config.js` file

```
module.exports = {
    entry : "./app/js/index.js",
    output : {
        path : __dirname + '/app/dist',
        filename : "./mapapp.js",
        publicPath : 'dist/'
    },
    module : {
        loaders : [ {
            test : /\.less$/,
            loader : "style!css!less"
        }, {
            test : /\.css$/,
            loader : "style!css"
        }, {
            test : /\.jsx$/,
            loader : "jsx"
        }, {
            test : /react-typeahead.*$/,
            loader : "jsx"
        }, {
            test : /\.(png|svg|woff|eot|ttf)/,
            loader : 'url-loader?limit=8192'
        } ]
    },
    resolve : {
        alias : {
            react : __dirname + '/node_modules/react',
            underscore : __dirname + '/node_modules/underscore/underscore',
            leaflet : __dirname + '/node_modules/leaflet/dist',
            'bootstrap-css-only' : __dirname
                    + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css',
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Does `npm install --save-dev react react-dom webpack` fix the issue?

Comment: @Aurora0001, thank you for your response. Now when I run `grunt` I get a bunc of errors and here are some `ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/less-loader!./app/css/select.less
Module build failed: variable @select-input-bg-disabled is undefined
 @ /home/.../techonmap/techonmap-v2/node_modules/react-select/less/control.less (line 33, column 20)
 near lines:
    &.is-disabled > .Select-control {
     background-color: @select-input-bg-disabled;
     &:hover {
 @ ./app/css/select.less 4:14-290
ERROR in ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMNullInputValuePropHook.js`

Comment: Could you edit that into your question and add your `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: @Newben your error is complaining about the Less variable `@select-input-bg-disabled` being undefined

Comment: @peteb yes but the code is supposed to compile correctly. My questionis how to correctly install `webpack`

Comment: @Aurora0001 sorry I have just seen your post, here's the update of this file !